# Loop validation, copy output from same range and paste in different ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping through 10 scenarios via a validation list. On each scenario the calculation engine provides an output in a fixed range. The output needs to be copied / pasted onto a dashboard sheet going down the row with fixed distance (so the dashboard sheet will have 10 sets of output).

The validation list, output and dashboard are in 3 different sheets

I tried the following VBA code, however on each run the output seems to be very different. I tried F8, the validation list looping is working, output is also changing correctly. But the pasting bit seems to differ every time I run, although some random stuff that gets copied are being pasted into the correct range.

Appreciate if someone can tell me what's wrong, thanks!
cross-post edit: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/loop-validation-copy-output-from-same-range-and-paste-in-different-ranges.1253137/

```
Sub LoopThroughScenarioList_And_PasteScenarioOutput()

Dim rng As Range
Dim dataValidationArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer 'used for # of scenario
Dim j As Integer 'used for # of output pasting
Dim rows As Integer

'Set the cell which contains the Scenario validation list 
Set rng = Sheets("LC model").Range("AC8") ':AJ8

On Error Resume Next 'in case there is error

'Create an array from our Data Validation formula so it knows the boundary of the loop
rows = Range(Replace(rng.Validation.Formula1, "=", "")).rows.Count
ReDim dataValidationArray(1 To rows)

For i = 1 To rows
    dataValidationArray(i) = _
        Range(Replace(rng.Validation.Formula1, "=", "")).Cells(i, 1)
Next i

'Loop through all the scenarios in array defined above
For i = LBound(dataValidationArray) To UBound(dataValidationArray)

    'Change the value in the scenario selection cell
    rng.Value = dataValidationArray(i)
    
    'Force the sheet to recalculate
    Application.Calculate
    
    'Copy the output
    Sheets("Macro to copy").Range("G6:H8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    'Paste the output, starting from Scenario 1 location
    'Sheets("Macro to copy").Range("M6").Offset(j, 0).Select 'j = 0 right now
    Sheets("Baseline & Scenario Output").Select
    Range("Q24").Offset(j, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
            
    'Update value j so next paste is on Scenario 2 location. 16 is the distance between each scenario output
    j = j + 16
      
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: One of the best first steps you can take is to [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Next step is comment out that `On Error Resume Next` so you can deal with any errors in your code

Comment: Put Option Explicit before your subroutine or function and declare (Dim) all variables, add some sample data. Then we will be able to suggest how to tackle this. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub LoopThroughScenarioList_And_PasteScenarioOutput()

    Dim rngVal As Range, arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long, wsCopy As Worksheet, wsBSO As Worksheet
    
    Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro to copy")
    Set wsBSO = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Baseline & Scenario Output")
    
    Set rngVal = Sheets("LC model").Range("AC8") 'cell with validation list
    arr = Range(Replace(rngVal.Validation.Formula1, "=", "")).Value 'get the list as a 2D array

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) 'Loop through all the scenarios in array defined above
        rngVal.Value = arr(i, 1)
        Application.Calculate
        With wsCopy.Range("G6:H8") 'transfer the values directly
            wsBSO.Range("Q24").Offset((i - 1) * 16).Resize( _
                       .rows.count, .Columns.count).Value = .Value
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this does the job! may i know what was your hypothesis of the bug in my original (and clearly inefficient code)?

Comment: `Sheets("Macro to copy").Range("G6:H8").Select` would error if that worksheet isn't selected: you can't select a range on an inactive sheet.

Comment: I see. Indeed should minimize the use of .Select. thank you!